# JMSJOBQueueBundle d'ont work with symfony 5.4

Tags: symfony5.4, jmsjobqueuebundle

i need help please if someone have idea about the subject

i used the JMSJOBQUEUEBundle with symfony 3.4 and it worked perfectly , and now i have to migrate my project to symfony v5.4 and i looked for a version compatible with v5.4 and i've found this [https://packagist.org/packages/olaldennis/job-queue-bundle]  but when i configured it and i started my tests, when i run this command "php bin/console jms-job-queue:run" i have this error

User Deprecated: The "JMS\JobQueueBundle\Entity\Type\SafeObjectType" class extends "Doctrine\DBAL\Types\ObjectType" that is deprecated Use {@link JsonType} instead.

[ci joint l'erreur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzqT9.png)